# Hamilton's paradox

Tags: voting-theory

We have the rule:

> We compare parties A and B in two different elections. If it happens that A wins votes and B loses votes, it cannot happen that A loses a seat and B wins a seat.

Concretely, I have to prove that Hamilton's method does not meet this rule by giving an example in which happens that A wins 2000 votes and B loses 2000 votes, A loses a seat, B wins a seat and the others stay the same.

I supose that the number of votes of A and B are big enough so that 2000 is a small amount and there is an extra party that increases the votes without changing the number of seats. But I am not able to find this example.

- What could be a suitable example?
- What would be the intuition to find such an example?

Comment: What is Huntington's method?  The usual paradoxes of this sort come down to rounding issues, as in the famous [Alabama Paradox](https://electowiki.org/wiki/Alabama_paradox)

Comment: Just to say, I thought Huntington-Hill avoided the Alabama and Population paradoxes and that therefore it must violate the quota rule.  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_paradox) appears to confirm that.  But, it's been a while since I looked at these things and I am hazy on the details.

Comment: @lulu I edited and explained how the Huntington's method works.

Comment: @lulu there was a mistake, it wasn't Huntington, it must be Hamilton's method.

Comment: The Hamilton method is the mechanism for apportioning seats to a state based on a per capita quotient; it has nothing to do with voting.

Comment: @higgs Could this quotient per capita be the vector of the percentages of votes (between 0 and 1) of each party multiplied by the number of seats?